# Can anyone explain why I'm getting the error about "same key"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am doing my React App, I don't know where I did a mistake.

The error is:

> "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `0`. Keys should
> be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates.
> Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted —
> the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
> at ul
> at Movies (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1439:5)
> at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:3780:29)
> at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:3982:29)
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:3411:30)
> at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:3032:35)
> at App"

My code:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Movies extends Component {

    state = {
        movies: [],
        isLoaded: false,
        error: null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:4000/v1/movies")
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("Status code is", response.status);
            if (response.status !== "200") {
              let err = Error;
              err.message = "Invalid response code: " + response.status;
              this.setState({error: err});
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((json) => {
            this.setState({
              movies: json.movies,
              isLoaded: true,
            },
            (error) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
              });
            }
            );
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        const {movies, isLoaded, error} = this.state;
        
        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        } else {
         return (
            <Fragment>
                <h2>Choose a movie</h2>

                <ul>
                    {movies.map((m) => (
                        <li key={m.id}>
                           <Link to={`/movies/${m.id}`}>{m.title}</Link>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </Fragment>
        );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You may have non-unique movie ids.**

*React uses component keys to determine which of the components in a collection needs to be re-rendered instead of just re-rendering the entire set of components every time anything changes.*

You can read more about keys and their uses at
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-react-keys-and-you

Can use indices as key:

```
{movies.map((m,i) => (
    <li key={i}>
       <Link to={`/movies/${m.id}`}>{m.title}</Link>
    </li>
 ))}
```

Here is an example of a similar warning when using duplicate keys and using indices as unique keys.
https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-snowflake-26v1o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: WOOOOOOOOWWWW THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: You should at least note the **pitfalls of using index as key**. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html): *"We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for [an in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys."*